# Closing the first pop up on a webpage with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

Hi I'm new to Selenium and trying to do some automation on a webpage. When it first loads up a pop up window is displayed. When I inspect the element the close button appears as follows

```js
<span title="Close" class="js-close-class offer-close"></span>
```

I am trying to close this pop up with the following code in my script:

```
driver.get("https://www.oddschecker.com/")
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
element = driver.find_element_by_class_name("js-close-class offer-close")
element.click()
time.sleep(10)
driver.quit()
```

This code is unable to find the element and will not close the pop up. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To click on the desired element you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.js-close-class.offer-close[title='Close']").click()
  ```
- Using `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//span[@class='js-close-class offer-close' and @title='Close']").click()
  ```

---

Ideally, to click on the element you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59130200/selenium-wait-until-element-is-present-visible-and-interactable/59130336#59130336) for the `element_to_be_clickable()` and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "span.js-close-class.offer-close[title='Close']"))).click()
  ```
- Using `XPATH`:

  ```
  WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//span[@class='js-close-class offer-close' and @title='Close']"))).click()
  ```
- **Note**: You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```